# onClick event of javascript not working in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jsp

In my JSP page, I am using `onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 "` to allow only the numbers. It is working fine with the website browsers.Well, it's not supported in mobile device browser(Google chrome).I have enabled javascript to execute. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555385/onclick-event-is-not-working-in-mobile-browser), but nothing happens. I have another issue, which will calculate the `value in input tag`, if the value is above 4999, it will display another input tag,it also not working in the mobile device. How can I resolve this?

Here is the code,

First button to enter values,which accepts only digit values

```
<input type="text" name="amount1" id="upload" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 && showFile()" required />
```

Hidden button,displayed when value is above 4999

```
<div id='openfile' style='display:none'><input type="file" class="form-control" name="panImg1" placeholder="Upload Your pancard image"  /></div>
```

Script file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showFile()
        {
            var choice = document.getElementById('upload').value;
            if (choice > 4999)
            {
                document.getElementById('openfile').style.display = 'block';
            } else
            {
                document.getElementById('openfile').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypress event is buggy in Google Chrome Mobile, and can be on mobile devices in general.. this should offer a fix

```
onkeyup="mobilePress(e)"
```

```js
function mobilePress(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    return false;
}
```

Or, you could listen to the "textInput" event on mobile and not deal with the RegExp. As for the issue, could your post more of your code and what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Hmm, is the element with the event handler an ancestor element? If so, this is probably the issue. It is registering the event there instead of on your input element.

Comment: @spartan you can make a call to

```e.stopPropagation()```

To prevent the event from bubbling up :)

Comment: It is also not effecting:(

Comment: After I have analyzed that, in some mobile phones, with the big screen, it's working fine, in some, not every, mobile phones, it is not working.All of them are Android, and their versions are all above version 5.0. Is there something connected to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript may not work in onKeypress of input tabs in some mobile phone's google chrome browser,if this problem arise use jquery for better performance,
here this code helped me `$(document).ready(function () {
$("#upload").on('input', function () {
                            if (v > 40000) {

               var v = "var v = "<div id='appDiv' class='col-md-4 inputGroupContainer'><input required='' type='text' name='panImg1' /></div>";
                                $('#newDiv').append(v);
                            }
            });
            });`

and added a Div in page
`<div id="newDiv"></div>`.In this type situations use jquery for better results.Thanks for helping me.