# How to run javascript on Chrome or Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I'm using javascript in my jsp file, on IE11 it run good, but I can not run and display on Chrome or Firefox browser, I have try to convert to jquery but no ok

This is my jsp:

```
<head>
   <script language="javascript">

   // functions
   function examStart()
   {
       ... 
   }

   function goout_onclick()
   {
       ...
   }
   function GetQ()
   {
       ...  
   }
   <script>
 </head>

<body>
     <input type="image" src="<%= imagesDir%>/bt_start.gif" <% if(yn_sametime.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) { %> onClick="JavaScript:examStart();" <% } else { %> onclick="JavaScript:examStart();" <% } %> id="startbutton" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('startbutton','','<%= imagesDir%>/bt_start_up.gif',1)" name="startbutton">
</body>
```

This is error happend from debug console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ScriptEngineMajorVersion is not defined
TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
```

How to run javascript on Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: yes, that's how you put javascript into a web page

Comment: tks your answer, but can you give more detail for me ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly how you put javascript into a web page. As your functions are just `...` what more do you want me to say? None of the "code" you've shown calls any of those functions, so, that's a place to start - also, `onClick="JavaScript:examStart();` should be `onClick="examStart();`

Comment: as per @JaromandaX answers addition to that if you are returning value from JS function then you can use like `onClick="return examStart();`

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes I put in web page, and in body of javascript is so long ,so I can not post, just need you get for me solution for this case

Comment: yes, remove javascript: from javascript:return examStart() etc

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX: I have try with: onClick="return examStart();, but it seem same error :(

Comment: you haven't mentioned an error until now, what is the error

Comment: @JaromandaX: Sorry I'm slow, I have updated error as above

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ScriptEngineMajorVersion is not defined` - and how are we supposed to know what is causing this error, because, indeed, you make no mention of `ScriptEngineMajorVersion` in the code you've posted thus far

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes maybe I'll check this error, I'm so sorry I don't mention on my posted

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX: it worked ! there a function check version, I try to comment out 'ScriptEngineMajorVersion', still use: 'onClick="return examStart();' and evething is well, thank so much !

Answer (score 0):

In some situation, javascript may not work in chrome, especially when you use this 'onclick' listener. SO it would be better if you can use the jquery instead.Use this jquery code to replace onclick in javascript. I had the same issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408491/onclick-event-of-javascript-not-working-in-mobile-device)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#but1").click(function(){
                   alert("The click has happened");
                   });
             }
             <input type='button' id='but1'/>
```

Comment: Tks for your answer, I will try to change to jquery base on your code..

Comment: Hope for a better result from you. Thank you.